# Cannot beat Namir due to dodgy AI in Director's Cut

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

My inventory is as follows:

- Tranquiliser Rifle with 50 rounds
- Stun Gun with 102 rounds
- PEP with 30 rounds
- 8 EMP grenades
- 6 gas grenades
- 3 EMP mines
- 2 gas mines
- 0 free slots (due to energy bars, bar packs, painkillers, stimpacks, Stop! worms and Nukes)

I read on the wiki that, for this fight, I can run into a small room and hack a security terminal to activate two bots to murder him. So, I activated the bots (had to use an AUD, because the bastard kept shooting me while I was hacking), and then... nothing. They never shot him. Even when he decloaked. I saw them bumping into him, even. Unless he cloaks really damn fast (I was using the Smart Vision aug to keep track of him), they were in the same room as him while he was decloaked several times. Needless to say, he has all the firepower. The best I can do is blast him with the PEP.

Do the bots actually do anything? Should I try turn around and get that turret in the grounds? Or is this a bug of some variety?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Though I never tried the bots myself, as I went entirely non-lethal and defeated him using emp grenades and the stun gun.

Comment: I may have to try that, then. Forgot that EMPs do damage. And I'm immune.

Comment: You could just drop some stuff, pick up weapons from around the room and kill him with those. Then sort out your inventory afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The bots should definitely be capable of killing Namir fairly easily (as he never targets them or attempts to destroy them), anecdotally I can state that this is how I defeated him myself in my first run of the Director's Cut, right down to the use of the AUD to hack the computer.

Are you definitely sure you hit 'Target enemies' and not one of 'Disable'/'Enable'? I can imagine a fair bit of muscle memory being at play if you're doing some sort of pacifist or no-alarms run as making the bots hostile to enemies runs contrary to both of these.

My advice would be to reattempt the fight the same way; at least now you know the location and can easily throw down an AUD to start up the bots again without too much fuss! It's possible some quirk of the AI had the bots fail to target him properly, he does still move around a lot which could cause some confusion. "Have you tried turning [the game] off and on again?"

If all else fails: you have all you need to kill Namir in the statues around the room(s). Every boss fight gives you ample supplies to account for the possibility that you're lacking in initial resources. Stunning him with any sort of grenade or mine will give you the opportunity to raid the nearest container before he opens fire. There should be a plasma rifle, combat rifle and/or revolver along with ammo and more grenades.

General combat strategy would be to hog corners (his plasma rifle kills you very quickly if you're in the open), stay alert to his movements and shoot him as he's jumping over walls since he is incapable of returning fire at this point. Be wary of the grenades he'll drop every now and then; he won't shoot for a few seconds after doing this move so you're free to turn and run, just be sure you're back in cover.

Answer (score 0):

I have no information on bots, maybe that is for Director's Cut version (I don't have that), but the most you can do with that inventory is to combine EMP and Gas mines to deploy together.

As far as I know, 1 gas grenade per area is effective at the same time, 2+ will do same damage as 1. So for maximum effect, your options will range from a few alpha strikes to all-that-can-go-with-a-gas-canister numbers. For me alpha strikes worked the best: making mine clusters and hitting him while stunned. For your inventory, I would just spam EMP grenades. Usually I eliminate Namir in lethal way, and you have several containers for that, which can help aside the inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same problem in the past and can't exactly remember how to do it anymore. But I did find the answer in [this ign article](http://www.ign.com/wikis/deus-ex-human-revolution/Jaron_Namir). I think I used the turret way to defeat him but well it was some years ago.

To post it here without spoilers:

> In the courtyard there is a turret. Dispose of the enemies around the turret and use the computer behind the turret to hack into it and set it to attack enemies. Next, pick up said turret and carry it to the elevator. Set down the turret outside the elevator but before the cutscene triggers (Set it outside the elevator with out getting out of it yourself) and then just lure the boss out of cover for a few seconds and let the turret do your dirty work for you